# Validation Error in get request fastAPI sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, rest, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have this route, that with the actual data in the DB table is supposed to answer with a 9 and 4 if i enter a 2 as parameter, but i get the error.

```
@userRoutes.get(
    "/users/userMatch/{idusuariobuscar}",
    response_model=list[PartidosUser],
    tags=["users"],
)
def get_user_matches(idusuariobuscar: str):
    return conn.execute(
        partidosusuarios.select(partidosusuarios.c.idpartido).where(
            partidosusuarios.c.idusuario == idusuariobuscar
        )
    ).fetchall()
```

[that queries this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndd9V.png)

This is the schema

```
class PartidosUser(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]
    idUsuario: str
    idPartido: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

And this the model of the table

```
partidosusuarios = Table(
    "partidosusuarios",
    meta,
    Column("idrelacion", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("idpartido", Integer),
    Column(
        "idusuario",
        Integer,
    ),
)
```

And the error

```
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for PartidosUser
response -> 0 -> idUsuario
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 0 -> idPartido
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 1 -> idUsuario
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> 1 -> idPartido
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only fetching the `idpartido` column from the database, hence the other fields don't exist. Changing your query from

```py
partidosusuarios.select(partidosusuarios.c.idpartido).where(
    partidosusuarios.c.idusuario == idusuariobuscar
)
```

to

```py
partidosusuarios.select().where(
    partidosusuarios.c.idusuario == idusuariobuscar
)
```

should solve your problem.

Also, be aware that since your Pydantic model contains an `id` field but your database model doesn't, this field will always be `None`. Also, your database field `idrelacion` is not included in the response. These might be intentional choices, or a naming error.